# Send message via Google Hangout from my android activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working on an application in which Google Hangout app is opening on a button click from my activity.Its working fine, but when i back press in the new Hangout intent its just closing the entire app, I want it to start the previous activity from which i started Hangout Intent, What should i do?

Code for starting Hangout intent i used is as follows

```
Intent hng = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
              hng.setType("text/plain");
              String message = code+" "+number+" "+amount;
              hng.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
              hng.setPackage("com.google.android.talk");
              startActivity(hng);
```